# Reorder icons in ubuntu-touch appmenu

Tags: ubuntu-touch, appmenu, groups

In Ubuntu touch, I'd like order icons in apps louncher (appmenu?) in a way that is pertinent for me. Is there a way to do that? I don't see how I could move or group them...

Answer (score 1):

I have found a sort of workaround by editing the 'Name' string in the `*.desktop` files found in `~/.local/share/applications` as the icons are sorted on these names. For gouping I gave all my games the prefix "Game:" Unfortunately the .desktop file for an app can be overwritten when upgrading the app so it's not a one-time-job but you may have to keep redoing it.

Comment: Thanks for your workaround, I might give it a try. But maybe I should also add it to the wish list for the developers ...